# CMake command line define macro without value

Tags: c++, cmake, command-line

I have the following line in my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
add_compile_definitions(DEBUG=$(DEBUG))
```

so when I compile my code with Makefile, I can do this

```
make DEBUG=1
```

But what I really want is to just define the `DEBUG` macro without setting any value to it.
Is there a way I can do this on a command line with cmake?

Comment: You can't do it. CMake build configs are for such purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With CMake you can, at configuration time, add some CMake variables. For example you can do this  `cmake -S <src_folder> -B <build_folder> -DDEBUG=ON`. This way you will have access to the variable `DEBUG` in your CMake.

In your CMake you will have this code

```
if(DEBUG)
   add_compile_definition(DEBUG)
endif()
```

(**Note** that instead of `add_compile_definitions`, it is recommended to use `target_compile_definitions` which will set your `DEBUG` macro only for one target and not globally to your project.
Example:

```
add_executable(my_target main.cpp)
target_compile_definition(my_target PRIVATE DEBUG)
```

`PRIVATE` means that this `compile_definition` will only be used by the target `my_target` and will not be propagated to others.)

But if you're only concern of the building type, I suggest that you use CMake variables that are already present within CMake. You can use `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` which will contains `Debug`, `Release` or whatever depending on what type of build you want. Your code will now be this

```
if("${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" STREQUAL "Debug")
   add_compile_definition(DEBUG)
endif()
```

And you can use this command line `cmake -S <src_folder> -B <build_folder> -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`

And here the documentation https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html?highlight=cmake_build_type

Note that this solution will only works for Mono-config generators like Makefile or Ninja and will not works with Visual Studio or Xcode

Comment: For multi-config generators, you have to check `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES`... However, except the "builtin" configuration names, a user may have any arbitrary names. So, instead of checking configuration type just leave a build option to the user.

Comment: Could you provide an example on how to use `target_compile_definitions`?

Comment: @MoneyBall I've edited my answer with an example

Comment: This was so helpful! Thank you!

Comment: @Stiven is there a way we can unset DEBUG from command line when we use `target_compile_definitions` without using `if(DEBUG)`? I have multiple macros that needs to be defined (e.g. `target_compile_definitions(my_target PRIVATE DEBUG USE_BOOST USE_YAML`). I'd like to turn each on/off from command line.

Comment: I don't know any way of unsetting variables from the command line. You can turn it to off wiith `-DDebug=OFF`. 
Be aware that the `DEBUG` in `if(DEBUG)` and in `target_compile_definitions(my_target PRIVATE DEBUG)` are two different things and are absolutely not related to each other. 
In `if(DEBUG)`, DEBUG is a variable and in  `target_compile_definitions(my_target PRIVATE DEBUG)` it's a string.